# Most common way to evaluate truthiness of string in vim

Tags: vim

In python to see if a string is non-empty, I'll do something like:

```
if STRING_VAR:
    ...
```

However, in vim a string doesn't really give a real truth-value when used directly. Is there a suggested way to evaluate the truthiness of a string? Usually I will use either:

```
if (STRING_VAR != "")
    ...
```

Or:

```
if (len(STRING_VAR) != 0)
    ...
```

What's the suggested/cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, in vim a string doesn't really give a real truth-value when used directly.

If programming were a religion then the Pythonistas would become zealots ;-) Say, for a C programmer the real truth is a number, and for an assembly one it's totally unaddressable and the Strings do not exist at all. So how can you speak of a "real truth" then?

VimScript is partially modelled after C and AWK. In particular, `:if` accepts only numeric values (zero is false, non-zero is true) including those "convertible" to numbers, such as... Strings. However, String-to-Number conversion is done like with `:h str2nr()`. And so `:if "hello world"` is legal but false.

So you'll probably want `:if empty(var)` instead.

Note however that `:h empty()` accepts any Vim type. Usually this is quite good, but on some rare occasions you prefer `:if len(var)` or `:if strlen(var)`.

The difference between `:h len()` and `:h strlen()` is that `strlen()` accepts Strings, while `len()` also accepts Lists and Dictionaries.

Still note that `:echo strlen(0)` is `1`, as Numbers are auto-converted to Strings anyway. And so if you want to check simultaneously that 1) `foo` has type of String, and 2) `foo` is empty then you have to write `:if foo is# ''`

Answer (score 3):

I would do `!empty(STRING_VAR)` *

---

I haven't looked how Vim compares strings. But remembering Vim is written in C, then if it is in similar manner to

```c
int string_compare(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 && (*s1 == *s2)) {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }
    return *s1 == *s2;
}
```

then `STRING_VAR != ""` is definitely better than `len(STRING_VAR) != 0`

The time complexity of former is O(1) - the result is after comparing first characters. The latter requires O(n) - for counting the length.

**On the other hand**, if string in Vim is represented by structure, e.g.

```c
struct string {
    char str[1000];
    int len;
};
```

then `len(STRING_VAR) != 0` will be just simple integer comparison (`var.len != 0`).

Actually, `len(STRING_VAR)` will be enough.

---

* As we rather can trust Bram, he implemented `empty()` in most efficient way

<sup>In Vim, like in Python, `if` doesn't require brackets</sup>